# Retrieve only one record from ONE-TO-MANY relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables. One is `Agent` and the other one is `Agent_Contact`. The `Agent_Contact` table is there to maintain the contact information of `Agent`.

The relationship from `Agent` to `Agent_Contact` is `One-To-Many` which means an `Agent` can have many `Agent_Contacts`

The `Agent_Contact` is holding the `Foreign Key` of `Agent`.

There can be `Agents` that who do not have any `Agent_Contact` as well.

Now, please have a look at the below code.

```
SELECT Agent.*,
Agent_Contact.*
FROM Agent
LEFT JOIN Agent_Contact ON Agent.idAgent = Agent_Contact.idAgent
```

Now, this returns all the `Agents` with their `Agent_Contact` s( If they have any). However imagine one `Agent` got 15 `Agent_Contact`s, then it will return 15 rows.

This is not what I want. Once `Agent_Contact` per one `Agent` is enough. But how can I modify the above sql query to achieve this task?

Comment: Instead of a JOIN use a subquery to get Agent_Contact data.

Comment: Highly recommend inner join instead of left join.

Comment: @HddnTHA And why? Do you understand why OP is using a `LEFT JOIN`? Hint: "There can be Agents that who do not have any Agent_Contact as well."

Comment: Simply add a where clause inside of query then

Comment: Take a where clause agentcontact.agentcontact_id =? Limit 1 is enouf for this query

Comment: @HddnTHA Nope, now you've got one `Agent` and the rest have been limited out.

Comment: Which agent_contact do you want? If the answer is 'it doesn't matter' then this is often indicative of poor design. It *should* matter!

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no rule to which contact must be returned, it is enough to add a group by clause.

```
SELECT Agent.*,
Agent_Contact.*
FROM Agent
LEFT JOIN Agent_Contact ON Agent.idAgent = Agent_Contact.idAgent
GROUP Agent.idAgent
```

Comment: This doesn't always work. Some systems would require you to use aggregate functions on your non-idAgent columns.

Comment: @LCIII I know this would not work on MS SQL, but it should work on mysql. What systems are you talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want 1 `agent_contact` returned per `agent` returned then the question is "which agent_contact do you want returned?"

That's like selecting a classroom full of 20 students and saying "Please return 1 student." Well...which student do you want?

When it comes to selecting your Agent_Contact, you could select then alphabetically, or the one with the longest name, or **something** that will reduce the number of agent_contacts down to 1.

This query selects the agent_contact with the maximum name. You can use whatever agent_contact column you want, it just has to be put in an aggregate function that will return only one kind.

```
SELECT t.Id, ac.* FROM
(SELECT Agent.Id, Max(AgentContact.Name)
FROM Agent
LEFT JOIN Agent_Contact ON Agent.idAgent = Agent_Contact.idAgent
GROUP BY Agent.Id) as t
INNER JOIN Agent_Contact as ac ON t.Name = ac.Name
```